# How do I fix my disorganized objects in my android studio layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have been playing around with my android studio 2.3.3.

I loaded a few widgets and text objects into my design platform and got this:

[image]

but every time I run the program i get this instead:

[image]

Below is the code in my layout.xml(activity_main.xml):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJPcA.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7rj6.png)

Comment: post your layout.xml .

Comment: I believe you are referring to the code in activity_main.xml. I've posted it.

Comment: thanks . i have found the solution cricket_007 & @ADM

Comment: If your using `ConstraintLayout` please add `Constraints` to inside views